# CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER not returning response

Tags: php, apache, curl, instagram

I have trying to query an Instagram API but the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER does not seems to work the way it is suppose to. The CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER has been set to true but i do not get a response all I get is a boolean. From what i have read the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true which i have done so below. Please advice. Thanks

```
public function __construct($uri) {
    $this->handler = curl_init($uri);
           $this->_setOptions();
}

protected function _setOptions() {
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::DEFAULT_USER_AGENT);

}

public function getResponse() {
    $response = curl_exec($this->handler);
    curl_close($this->handler);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might solve it by writing your function as follows:

```
protected function _setOptions() {
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::DEFAULT_USER_AGENT);
}
```

this way you avoid to check the ssl protocol.

As an extra option you could set **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**:

```
curl_setopt($this->handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

It is recommended to always work under secure SSL conditions in production environments, as it is mentioned in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST should be set to 2 to ensure a secure SSL connection.

Comment: I think that was the answer, even if the topic was from 2012!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Boolean false?

If its false, you must have an error.

Add the folowing after your curl_exec line:

```
if(curl_errno($this->handler)) 
{
   echo curl_error($this->handler);
}
```

Comment: The Error Message I've got is this:
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I am trying to run this URL:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nyp/media/recent?client_id=db5ec075c6da4224aafcf55bf3a0bc43

It is able to run on the browser but not on the application. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the getResponse() method after you call new ClassName('http://someurl.com')?

try this

```
$x = new ClassName('http://www.google.com');
var_export($x->getResponse();
```

EDIT: you can also call add an error output method to see if some curl error happened

```
public function last_error() {
    echo curl_error($this->handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r(curl_getinfo($this->handler));` right after `curl_exec($this->handler);` to figure what the problem is.